# Material UI select multiple dates with Calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar, material-ui

I am implementing this [Calendar component from Material UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/8d9de123e3e58a5e28e96e74be52c808f8a42d05/src/DatePicker/Calendar.js) and would like to be able to select multiple dates. When another date is selected it should remain highlighted. Below is what I have so far.

```
import React from 'react';
import Calendar from 'material-ui/DatePicker/Calendar';

class MultiCalendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            controlledDate: null,
        };
    }

    handleChange = (event, date) => {
        console.log('HERE');
        this.setState({
                controlledDate: date,
            });
         console.log(date);
         console.log(this.state.controlledDate);
    };

render() {
return (
    <Calendar 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
        value={this.state.controlledDate} 
        className='calendar-test' id='calendar' 
        firstDayOfWeek={0} style={{ width: '500px' }}>
    </Calendar>

        );
      }
    }

export default MultiCalendar
```

(1) [I can see here that the issue has been closed](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5800) but I am not sure where to find the solution.

(2) The onChange event is not firing because those statements never appear in the console.

Any help with these issues would be wonderful. Thanks

Comment: I think this can help : http://clauderic.github.io/react-infinite-calendar/#/enhance-default-functionality/multiple-date-selection?_k=ose43z

Answer (score 10):

You can use StaticDatePicker and the property renderDay to allow many dates. The dates selected will be saved in **values**.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import StaticDatePicker from "@mui/lab/StaticDatePicker";
import PickersDay from "@mui/lab/PickersDay";
import startOfDay from "date-fns/startOfDay";

const CustomPickersDay = styled(PickersDay, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "selected"
})(({ theme, selected }) => ({
  ...(selected && {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
    "&:hover, &:focus": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark
    },
    borderTopLeftRadius: "50%",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: "50%",
    borderTopRightRadius: "50%",
    borderBottomRightRadius: "50%"
  })
}));

export default function MultiDatePicker() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState([startOfDay(new Date())]);

  const findDate = (dates, date) => {
    const dateTime = date.getTime();
    return dates.find((item) => item.getTime() === dateTime);
  };

  const findIndexDate = (dates, date) => {
    const dateTime = date.getTime();
    return dates.findIndex((item) => item.getTime() === dateTime);
  };

  const renderPickerDay = (date, selectedDates, pickersDayProps) => {
    if (!values) {
      return <PickersDay {...pickersDayProps} />;
    }

    const selected = findDate(values, date);

    return (
      <CustomPickersDay
        {...pickersDayProps}
        disableMargin
        selected={selected}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <StaticDatePicker
        displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
        label="Week picker"
        value={values}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          //copying the values array 
          const array = [...values];
          const date = startOfDay(newValue);
          const index = findIndexDate(array, date);
          if (index >= 0) {
            array.splice(index, 1);
          } else {
            array.push(date);
          }
          setValues(array);
        }}
        renderDay={renderPickerDay}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        inputFormat="'Week of' MMM d"
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

The dependencies used in the example are:

- @emotion/react latest (11.8.2)
- @emotion/styled latest (11.8.1)
- @mui/lab latest (5.0.0-alpha.72)
- @mui/material latest (5.5.0)
- date-fns latest (2.28.0)
- react latest (17.0.2)
- react-dom latest (17.0.2)

The view is.

[image]

Comment: great answer ,but  while handling onChange , you are not copying the value array , can you please correct that if it's a mistake.

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: This is so convoluted..

Comment: Thanks @andres.ara. And this's a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-mui-date-picker-forked-4fz7nf?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: Hello, I took your code and modified your imports because the component was not showing and now the component is showing correctly but when I click on a date I get an infinite loop error (too many re-renders): "The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(StaticDatePicker)> component".
Did you also have this problem?

Comment: Fitspade you can see the demo done by Amr Eraky https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-mui-date-picker-forked-4fz7nf?file=/Demo.tsx using the code.

Comment: Yes I know, but when I implement the demo, it doesn't work in my project like I said.. Need to change the imports and have infinite loop when onChange is trigger